# Unit base vectors in a new coordinate system

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, coordinate-systems, change-of-basis

Let's assume we have a function $f:\Omega =R^2 \rightarrow R $

$f(x,y)=x+2xy+x^2y$. Obviously our unit base vectors on $\Omega$ are  $e_x=\hat{i}$ and  $e_y=\hat{j}$.

Now we want to change the variables $u=x$ and $v=xy$. As a result;

$f(u,v)=u+2v+uv$

How should the unit vectors $e_u$ and  $e_v$  be defined in the new coordinate $(u,v)$, so that for example, we can compute directional derivative $\nabla f. \hat{e}_u=\Large(\frac{\partial  f}{ \partial u}\hat{e}_u+\frac{\partial  f}{ \partial v}\hat{e}_v). \hat{e}_u$ in the new coordinate?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a pretty standard way.
$$\vec r = (x, y)$$
$$ x= u$$
$$ y = \frac vu$$
$$ \vec r_u=(1, -\frac v{u^2})$$
$$ \vec r_v=(0, \frac 1{u})$$
$$||\vec r_u ||=\sqrt{1+{(\frac v{u^2})}^2}$$
$$||\vec r_v ||=\sqrt{{(\frac 1{u})}^2}$$
$$\vec e_u = \frac {(1, -\frac v{u^2})}{\sqrt{1+{(\frac v{u^2})}^2}} $$
$$\vec e_v = \frac {(0, \frac 1{u})}{\sqrt{{(\frac 1{u})}^2}} $$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you tell me how  you wrote $\vec r_u$ and  $\vec r_v$ ? And also do you know what this standard process is calls?

Comment: This is by definition of unit base vector (which is what I mean standard). And for the first question, $ \vec r_u = (\frac {dx}{du}, \frac {dy}{du})$

Comment: Alles Klar! Thanks again.